# IdentityServer4 SPA Login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I want to create an SPA, and Login Via my custom Login Screen (Frontend is in React&Redux), but i miserably fail at it.

So basically i´ll get an 404 Error returned, when using

```js
    const username = 'bob'
    const password = 'bob'
    const returnUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/'

    fetch('https://localhost:5000/api/Authenticate/Login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password,
        returnUrl,
      }),
```

the response I get is always: **POST https://localhost:5000/api/Authenticate/Login net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

The Backend looks like:

```cs
            services.AddCors(setup =>
            {
                setup.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001");
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                    policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                    policy.AllowCredentials();
                        //.WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, "x-custom-header");
                });
            });
```

and in the Configure Method as `app.UseCors();`

My IdentityServer4, wont Log any Errors nor an Log in anyway.

Here an Gist of the related Files: https://gist.github.com/TheRealLenon/2da8ccebd1b1699ff3afd3d3612bf971

But when changing it to `policy.AllowAnyOrigin();` i´ll get the following Log in my Server: `System.InvalidOperationException: The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time. Configure the CORS policy by listing individual origins if credentials needs to be supported.`
And the Response is: `POST https://localhost:5000/api/Login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Do you have any idea, what is wrong? Or anyone else? This is confusing, because theres nothing helpful i could found on the Internet with CORS and the 404 Error..
When appending `app.UseAuthentication();` i will get the following error-Message: `CORS request made for path: /api/Login from origin: https://localhost:5001 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint` which confuses me, because i´ve defined it within:

```cs
            services.AddCors(setup =>
            {
                setup.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001");
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                    policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                    policy.AllowCredentials();
                        //.WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, "x-custom-header");
                });
            });
```

Ive also tried it with multiple Endpoints, in case I´ve  mismatched the "Route" in my AuthenticateController, but I can set it like I want, the result will be the Same.

Comment: It says the url is not found, have you checked the controller, does the endpoint start with api? Please verify and come back.

Comment: As in the Gist shown, the Controller has the **[Route("api/[controller]")]** Routing. And to access the Method I need also the Method name, so it should work?, but it actually doesn't matter, which type of "URL" I enter for testing like lowercase, removing the login or so, it still won't work.

PS: I´ve shared the wrong Codebase. The Codebase now (especially the Gist) is the actual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are defining the clients on `Config.cs`, the default CORS implementation will be in use. You just need to add the spa app's `origin` to `AllowedCorsOrigins` when defining the client

```
                new Client
                {
                    ...

                    AllowedCorsOrigins =
                        { 
                            "http://localhost:5001" 
                        },

                    ...
                },
```

Note `http://localhost:5001` is the origin and `http://localhost:5001/` is the url

**Edit**:

To have login UI on SPA app, you also need to modify `Startup` class of IdentityServer to add cors, here is details:

1. Add this code to `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

2. And this code to `Configure` method

```
app.UseCors("default");
```

Comment: I´ve Updated my Client in the Config with your suggestion.

The AuthenticateControler has the following Route Attribute: `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. Because The Method which should called is ` Login([FromBody]LoginRequest request)` The complete Endpoint I call is: `https://localhost:5000/api/Authenticate/Login`.
But this will Result in the Same Output as before: **CORS request made for path: /api/Authenticate/Login from origin: https://localhost:5001 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint**
You can see the Updates in the Gist provided above.

Comment: I see, you are trying to ajax call to IdentityServer. I replicated your issue on my local, all we need to do is to enable cors like what we did for api clients, here is code to ass on `Startup.cs` of IdentityServer project: 1. Add ```services.AddCors(options => {options.AddPolicy("default", policy => { policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5001").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();});});
```  in `ConfigureServices` method. 2- `app.UseCors("default");` on `Configure` method right before `app.UseIdentityServer()` - Let me know if it works, then I'll update the main answer @Lenon

Comment: @Lenon Dont forget to add `.AllowCredentials()` in favour of `CSRF`

Comment: I could kind of get it to manage. But It seems, that the custom ReturnUrlParser, won't work this way... This is weird.

Comment: how did you make it work? any different from suggested solutions?  @Lenon about `ReturnUrlParser`, its because of [this line of code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/OidcReturnUrlParser.cs#L62), as in your, UI is not local, to fix you can add a custom `ReturnUrlParser` and register it like this: `services.AddTransient<IReturnUrlParser, SpaReturnUrlParser>();`

Comment: There was something weird, when having Multiple Cors allowed. After removing it from the Startup, it worked. With the Default script, as shown.

Yeah this is working fine. But the Response there is a bit weird, because it wants an return url which looks like: **https://localhost:5002/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=client&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5002/dashboard&response_type=code&scope=api**. And there I don't get around :)

Comment: Custom parser should fix your issue, [here](https://github.com/karpikpl/identity-server4-with-SPA-UI/blob/master/id4/src/IdentityServer/ReturnUrlParser.cs). checkout whole repo, its a good example

Comment: This is exactly, how I set it up :) The thing is, that I call it directly, but then the ReturnUrl will be parsed as null. It's something weird with The getQueryVariable..

Comment: But tbh I’ll try to get an workaround with kind of workaround to get it working without getting redirected to the Login Page.

Comment: good luck, let me know if I can help, updating my main answer for cors now @Lenon