# IdentityServer4 - "path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cors, identityserver4

I have a .netcore 3.1 MVC project that is using IdentityServer4 hybrid flow.

The identityServer has an AuthenticationProperties with ExpiresUtcset (1 hour).

On the MVC client, there's a cookie with SlidingExpiration (false) and ExpireTimeSpan (15 minutest).

After logging in to the application, the application cookie shows that it has an expiry of 1 hour. If I refresh or change to another page within the application, the application cookie gets the expiry extended. So far, this are all working as expected.

However, things get hairy if I try to do ajax calls on a page. If I stay on a page for a while (more than 15 minutes) without refreshing, the ajax calls fail with a Http error 0. When looking through the IdentityServer logs, it shows:

> CORS request made for path: /connect/authorize from origin:
>   http://localhost:5100 but was ignored because path was not for an
>   allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
>
> No CORS policy found for the specified request.

To deal with that, the following was added in the startup.cs ConfigureServices for the identityServer.

```
    var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(log)
    {
        AllowAll = true
    };

    services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5100")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
```

In configure, app.UseCors() was added.

However the same error messages in IdentityServer still comes up.

Has anyone faced similar issues, or know what I'm doing wrongly?

Comment: Did u add app.UseCors() in configure method?

Comment: Yeah, that was added.

Comment: @Monkey I suggest to try couple of things: 1. try to add name for the policy 2. Add `AllowCredentials` 3. make sure `app.UseCors("default")` is listed before `app.UseAuthentication()`  - here is another post with code sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809873/identityserver4-spa-login/61812421#61812421

Answer (score 1):

You also may need to add CORS in your client settings. See [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html). You have to add your URL in AllowedCorsOrigins settings for your client.

Comment: Yeah, I did missed this in the client settings. Sadly, I'm still seeing the same error message after adding it in. Big thanks though!

Comment: @Monkey Strange. When I get this CORS error just setting the CORS policy fixes it. There may be some problem elsewhere. Sometimes just the order of app.UseCors() also makes a difference, so I just put in on top of the method. Or maybe it something else, hard to say.

Comment: For the last month I have been working on Identity Server based projects. I of course get CORS issues. In all of these I just use this bit of code for CORS, where you create a custom policy and it just works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did use the code from MS to set the CORS policy. Will try playing around with the order of app.UserCors().

Answer (score -1):

Calling the app.UseCors() before app.UseEndpoints() in Configure method will solve this issue.